# Logical OR ( || ) working different in 2 versions of MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, logical-or

When used in where clause

1. `select * from tableA where col like 'value' || col = val ;`
2. `select * from tableA where col like 'value' or col = val ;`

I experience two different behaviors:

- Both 1 & 2 work the same in version ( 10.2.14 )
- Only 2 works as expected in version ( 10.3.22 )

I tried to look at release log for 10.3.22 but nothing was mentioned regarding the change to logical `OR`. Has anyone faced the issue if so just want to confirm there are changes between different versions of Maria DB ?

or its somethign else i shuld be looking at ?

Answer (score 0):

Check that if you have the [`PIPES_AS_CONCAT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/#pipes_as_concat) SQL_MODE set in the 10.3.22. If not, show the data that is giving you trouble.

Comment: Hi slaakso , thanks for the reply .I verified and it's STRICT_TRANS_TABLE , which seems to be default and same as in the 10.2.14 and 10.3.22.